# Guitar tablature

Tags: guitar, tablature

When notes are arranged slid to left and slid to right on the Guitar tab which one (note) string is first played:B G D or D G B? in the these two bars? and why?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In this tableture, you would play D, G, B in the first bar, and B, G, D in the second bar. You always play the notes from left to right.  If two notes are exactly above each other, like

```
E:---------
B:---0-----
G:---0-----
D:---------
A:---------
E:---0-----
```

then you play the notes at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The left part is played D-G-B and the right part is B-G-D.

You read notes from left to right, the same way we read texts.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know the music tune you are playing, always look for TAB with the music score above the TAB to indicate timing and (obvious) note progression to play etc. 
TAB  written out with those things included, helps too:
[image: the start of "Moon River" with time and recommended fretboard fingering]

Comment: Really don't think the stems help a lot. Obviously in 1st full bar, it's minim/crotchet (or is it the other way round?) Is bar 7 crotcher/minim? It would be better if the numbers were spread out appropriately (1/3 - 2/3)as in bar 7, were there more notes on the second part, the stem couldn't be long. Proper notation as well is the better way.